# SQL subquery / select subset of data from separate table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing an SQL query to extract the printing usage for individual cartridges. I've got the main body of the query down as below but I'm having trouble selecting some specific data to do with the meter readings stored in a separate table.

The below query lists cartridges put into printers with the date they were activated and the date they were deactivated. I would then like to use a MeterReadings table to see what the usage was over that period using the ActivatedDate and DeactivatedDate based on the DeviceID. What I have so far is below

```
SELECT Devices.DeviceID, 
    Devices.DeviceDescription, 
    DeviceConsumables.ConsumableVariantID,
    ConsumableVariants.Type,
    ConsumableDescriptions.Description,
    MAX(ConsumableReadings.ReadingDate) as DeactivatedDate,
    MIN(ConsumableReadings.ReadingDate) AS ActivatedDate,
    ConsumableReadings.ChangedDate,
    CASE ConsumableVariants.ColourID
    WHEN 1 THEN MAX(MeterReadings.TotalMono) - MIN(MeterReadings.TotalMono)
    ELSE MAX(MeterReadings.TotalColour) - MIN(MeterReadings.TotalColour)
    END AS PrintingDiff,
    ConsumableVariants.ExpectedPageCoverage,
    ConsumableVariants.ExpectedPageYield

FROM Devices

LEFT JOIN DeviceConsumables ON Devices.DeviceID = DeviceConsumables.DeviceID
LEFT JOIN ConsumableVariants ON DeviceConsumables.ConsumableVariantID = ConsumableVariants.ConsumableVariantID
LEFT JOIN ConsumableReadings ON DeviceConsumables.ConsumableID = ConsumableReadings.ConsumableID
LEFT JOIN ConsumableDescriptions ON ConsumableVariants.DescriptionID = ConsumableDescriptions.ConsumableDescriptionID
LEFT JOIN MeterReadings ON DeviceConsumables.DeviceID = MeterReadings.DeviceID

WHERE ConsumableVariants.Type = '3' -- To only get toner cartridges
    AND Devices.DeviceID = '24'
    AND MeterReadings.ScanDateTime > MIN(ConsumableReadings.ReadingDate)
    AND MeterReadings.ScanDateTime < MAX(ConsumableReadings.ReadingDate)

GROUP BY devices.DeviceID, Devices.DeviceDescription,
    DeviceConsumables.ConsumableVariantID, ConsumableVariants.Type, ConsumableDescriptions.Description,
    ConsumableReadings.ChangedDate, ConsumableVariants.ColourID, ConsumableVariants.ExpectedPageCoverage,
    ConsumableVariants.ExpectedPageYield

ORDER BY Devices.DeviceID
```

This is currently generating the error "An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference."

The calculated fields ActivatedDate and DeactivatedDate are the date ranges I will require. I want to use the case statement to select MAX(MeterReadings.TotalMono) - MIN(MeterReadings.TotalMono) for black and white or MAX(MeterReadings.TotalColour) - MIN(MeterReadings.TotalColour) for colour. This would effectively give me the usage as readings can only go upwards. This would hopefully give me the starting point usage with the MIN and ending point usage with the MAX for the specific DeviceID.

As shown above I'm joining on my MeterReadings table on DeviceID.

I can't figure out how to get the MeterReadings for device x between y and z (where x is DeviceID, y is ActivatedDate and z is DeactivatedDate) so I can then add a calculated column into the case statement. Any help appreciated.

-- Edit
For brevity I won't add all the schema in here but what should be enough.

**Devices** - list of all known devices

DeviceID

DeviceDescription

lots of extra fields that describe the device

**DeviceConsumables** - What devices use what consumables

ConsumableID

DeviceID - Forign key to device

ConsumableVariantID - Forign key to ConsumableVariant

**ConsumableVariant** - list of all the consumable variants there are

ConsumableVariantID

Type - 3 here indicates toner, what I'm interested in

**ConsumableReadings**

ReadingID - PK

ConsumableID - forign key to DeviceConsumables

ReadingDate - last time a reading was taken

ChangedDate - last time a new cartridge was inserted

**MeterReadings**

ReadingID - PK not to do with PK of consumablereadings

DeviceID

ScanDateTime - time usage scan was taken

TotalMono - total mono at scan time

TotalColour Total colour at scan time

Comment: ignoring your last Case statement/field (PrintingDiff) that you have in your query, does everything else work? (Does it return your max and min values that you have defined in columns 5 and 6 (DeactivatedDate, ActivatedDate)?)

Comment: Hi, yes, ignoring my final case statement I get the rows I've defined. The ActivatedDate and DeactivatedDate are correctly grouped against ChangedDate (as whenever a changedate is logged it indicates a new cartridge was put in.)

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: Sorry for being slightly unclear.. well previously I was getting erroneous data. The numbers coming out were too high. I think I might need to add a where clause into the join on MeterReadings. I've updated my post with what I've got now but this is generating


"An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have to break you queries into nested queries ... Below query is not tested, so it may have some syntax problem, but it gives a way to find out what you are looking for ...

```
SELECT Devices.DeviceID, 
    Devices.DeviceDescription, 
    DeviceConsumables.ConsumableVariantID,
    ConsumableVariants.Type,
    ConsumableDescriptions.Description,
    A.DeactivatedDate,
    A.ActivatedDate,
    A.ChangedDate,
    CASE ConsumableVariants.ColourID
    WHEN 1 THEN MAX(MeterReadings.TotalMono) - MIN(MeterReadings.TotalMono)
    ELSE MAX(MeterReadings.TotalColour) - MIN(MeterReadings.TotalColour)
    END AS PrintingDiff,
    ConsumableVariants.ExpectedPageCoverage,
    ConsumableVariants.ExpectedPageYield

FROM Devices

LEFT JOIN DeviceConsumables ON Devices.DeviceID = DeviceConsumables.DeviceID
LEFT JOIN ConsumableVariants ON DeviceConsumables.ConsumableVariantID = ConsumableVariants.ConsumableVariantID
LEFT JOIN ConsumableReadings ON DeviceConsumables.ConsumableID = ConsumableReadings.ConsumableID
LEFT JOIN ConsumableDescriptions ON ConsumableVariants.DescriptionID = ConsumableDescriptions.ConsumableDescriptionID
LEFT JOIN 
(
   SELECT D.DeviceID,
          MAX(CR.ReadingDate) as DeactivatedDate,
          MIN(CR.ReadingDate) AS ActivatedDate,
          CR.ChangedDate
     FROM Devices D
     LEFT JOIN DeviceConsumables DC ON D.DeviceID = DC.DeviceID
     LEFT JOIN ConsumableReadings CR ON DC.ConsumableID = CR.ConsumableID
    WHERE D.DeviceID = '24'
    GROUP BY D.DeviceID, 
            CR.ChangedDate
) AS A ON DeviceConsumables.DeviceID = A.DeviceID
LEFT JOIN MeterReadings ON A.DeviceID = MeterReadings.DeviceID
WHERE ConsumableVariants.Type = '3' -- To only get toner cartridges
    AND Devices.DeviceID = '24'
    AND MeterReadings.ScanDateTime > A.ActivatedDate
    AND MeterReadings.ScanDateTime < A.DeactivatedDate

GROUP BY devices.DeviceID, Devices.DeviceDescription,
    DeviceConsumables.ConsumableVariantID, ConsumableVariants.Type, ConsumableDescriptions.Description,
    ConsumableReadings.ChangedDate, ConsumableVariants.ColourID, ConsumableVariants.ExpectedPageCoverage,
    ConsumableVariants.ExpectedPageYield

ORDER BY Devices.DeviceID
```

Comment: Thanks very much, just tested this and it appears to have resolved my issues. I didn't realise I'd have to break it into a nested query.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd add to your output the ColourID so you know if you are reading the Mono or Colour values. Second, I believe if you remove the ConsumableID from your group by clause, it should work. ConsumableID rows have one date, and if you include that in your group by, you'll never be able to get a max and min, therefore the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately this hasn't remedied my problem - with that I am getting a print diff output but it's way too high so my theory is it's getting the MAX and MIN for the whole table, not just for the deviveID over the period I want to specify

Comment: Can you throw in some example data and schema so I can actually try writing it out?

Comment: Sure thing, I'll add an edit to my original post with some extra information.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your join statement.

Change the following line:

```
LEFT JOIN ConsumableTypes ON ConsumableVariants.Type = ConsumableVariants.Type
```

To something like:

```
LEFT JOIN ConsumableTypes ON ConsumableVariants.Type = ConsumableTypes.Type
```

(or whatever table you are joining to).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, I noticed that two mins ago. Silly mistake to have made! I've fixed that but it isn't helping with my usage numbers as I think I'm needing to join on my meterreadings table but limit the range to my activateddate and deactivateddate.